# Serre fibrations and pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration, pullback

Let $h:Y \to B$ be a surjective Serre fibration and let the following be a pullback diagram.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> E @.  \\
@VfVV @VgVV \\
Y @>>h> B @. 
\end{CD}$$
Then $g$ is a Serre fibration iff $f$ is one.

---

Showing that $g$ Serre fibration implies $f$ Serre fibration is just a simple application of the pullback property and doesn't use any property of $h$.

I'm struggling with proofing the other direction. I tried the following:

---

In order to show that $p:E\to B$ is a Serre fibration, consider the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D^n @>>> E @.  \\
@VVV @VgVV \\
D^n \times I @>k>> B. @. 
\end{CD}$$We now need to show that there exists  a lift $D^n\times I \to E$.

If I could show that there exists a continuous map $D^n \to Y$, such that the diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D^n @>>> Y @.  \\
@VVV @VhVV \\
D^n\times I @>k>> B. @. 
\end{CD}$$

commutes, we could use the lifitng prop of the Serre fibration $h$ and the pullback property to induce a comm. diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D^n @>>>X @>>> E @.  \\
@VVV @VfVV @VgVV \\
D^n\times I @>>>Y @>>h> B @. 
\end{CD}$$ and use the lifting prop. of the Serre fibration $f$ to get a lift $D^n\times I \to E$. Without such a map

### Can I assure that there is such a continuous map $D^n \to Y$?

---

Using surjectivity I get such a map in set, but this isn't necessary continuous.
Without such a map, I don't see how I could proof this statement.

Comment: Use that fact that $k_0:D^n\rightarrow B$ is null-homotopic to find a lift...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I considered this at first but didn't think of glueing my null-homotopy to $k$, in order to get a commutative diagram...